# What should I do to reveal the whole string?

Tags: html, firefox, canvas

It's really strange that it works when globalCompositeOperation is 'source-atop',but it fails when globalCompositeOperation is ''destination-atop'.It seems that different types of words can not be showed together.Here is code snippet.

```js
window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
let FirstTime=Date.now();
function draw(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    const width_mid=canvas.width/2;
    const height_mid=canvas.height/2;
    var timeStamp=Date.now();
    var num=Math.floor((timeStamp-FirstTime)/300);
    if(num>15)
        return;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    ctx.font = "200px 华文行楷";
    ctx.textAlign="center";
    ctx.fillText("CHH算法网",width_mid,height_mid+40);
    // ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-atop';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,300);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(70,100,200,70);
    var end_x=200;
    var bezier_x;
    for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            end_x+=10;
            bezier_x=end_x+100;
        }
        else{
            end_x+=200;
            bezier_x=end_x-130;
        }
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(bezier_x,i%2?100:100,end_x,i%2?70:280);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle="white";
    ctx.lineWidth=200;
    ctx.stroke();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: rgb(255, 213, 0);
}
#btn{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    left:40%;
    top:70px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 200px;
    color:white;
    background-color: rgb(25, 99, 145);
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Typewriter";
    border:none;
}
#btn:hover{
    color:rgb(25, 99, 145);
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1300px" height="300px"></canvas>
```

I changed the globalCompositeOperation,finding that only one type of words could be showed if globalCompositeOperation is 'destination-atop'.What I was hoping to do is to use the brush as an eraser to erase the yellow color and the title below it would emerge gradually.

Comment: I tested your code (and turned it into a snippet after seeing that most of your dependencies werent needed anyway) and it seems to have the right effect. What are you asking here though? I don't see any "yellow" in your code so I'm unsure what you want to accomplish here. Global composite operations are one-and-done operations, and you can lose data there - so whatever you drew before can be discarded is necessary, meaning you might need more canvasses as buffer to draw many different things.

Comment: maybe I don't explain it clearly,you see,when globalCompositeOperation is 'destination-atop',I could only see "算法网",but it is supposed to be "CHH算法网".However,when globalCompositeOperation is 'source-atop',I could see "CHH算法网" and that's right.I am wondering how to fix it...cause i just want the display effect when  globalCompositeOperation is 'destination-atop'.THE PROBLEM ONLY HAPPENS ON FIREFOX.

Comment: Okay, maybe good to mention it only happens in Firefox (which, in that case, seems more like a FF bug). The only thing that changes when you switch those operations is basically whether the text is written over your current image or under your current image before emptying the existing pixels. So again, I'm not sure how to help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why your issue is limited to Firefox, but the solution here is to simply make sure your context is *reset* correctly every time you start drawing. I found adding `ctx.save()` before doing anything and `ctx.restore()` after completing your loop fixes your issue, though I am unsure why it only applies to the CH letters and not the other characters. Either way, it's safe to do so and every browser supports it. It's also good practice to do that anyway to ensure you never wind up in a context where you unsure of the state it is in.

Another issue with this persistent composite operation is that, since you aren't resetting it *and you aren't clearing the canvas*, the operation is technically applied to the pixels that *already* exist. It's therefor best to do both: clear your context and clear your canvas. In the snippet below I have done both:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById( "myCanvas" );
const ctx = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
const width_mid = canvas.width / 2;
const height_mid = canvas.height / 2;

let time = null;
let useSourceAtop = false;

function draw( timeStamp ){

  if( time === null ) time = timeStamp;
  
  const num = Math.floor((timeStamp-time)/300);
  
  if( num  > 15 ) return;
  
  ctx.save(); // <- save the current state of your context - and since we have made no changes to it, this means save the current, reset context
  ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height ); // <-- Clear the canvas so you don't draw over the same pixel (this could mess with things such as anti-aliasing as a 50% alpha pixel would continuously get printed, making it more opaque etc)
  ctx.font = "200px 华文行楷";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText( "CHH算法网", width_mid, height_mid+40 );
  
  if( useSourceAtop ) ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
  else ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo( 0, 300 );
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo( 70, 100, 200, 70 );
  
  let end_x = 200;
  let bezier_x;
  
  for( let i = 0; i < num; i++ ){
  
      if( i%2 == 0 ){ 
      
          end_x += 10;
          bezier_x = end_x + 100;
          
      } else {
      
          end_x += 200;
          bezier_x = end_x - 130;
          
      }
      
      ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
        bezier_x,
        i%2 ? 100 : 100,
        end_x,
        i%2 ? 70 : 280
      );
      
  }
  
  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  ctx.lineWidth = 200;
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore(); // <-- reset any changes made to your context, like globalCompositeOperation, transforms, lineWidths, colors, etc... to the last time you saved them.
    
  window.requestAnimationFrame( draw );

}

window.requestAnimationFrame( draw );

document.addEventListener( 'dblclick', event => {
  
  event.preventDefault();
  useSourceAtop = !useSourceAtop;
  time = null;
  window.requestAnimationFrame( draw );
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 213, 0);
}
canvas {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1300px" height="300px"></canvas>
```

I also took the liberty to add some whitespace to your code, I know, it's a preference first and foremost, but I think legible code with breathing space makes it easier to parse and communicate about it. My eyes don't have to try to recognise the difference between characters smashed together.

Comment: Good luck with coding! Happy to help.